# Background top cutting from image

Tags: css

I have a [site](http://fahaduddin.com/mattbertulli/) on which the background of the image gets cut off even if the height is increased. How can I have the top area of the image on the page too?

```
.top-area {
    background: url(../img/matt.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 677px;
}
```

Comment: change `center center` to `top center`?

Comment: @MichaelCoker: Tried it. Does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `.top-area` to this. You're using `fixed` background attachment, so you need to modify the background position to clear your navigation (which is 78px tall), so move the background image down 78px. I also added a margin-top of 28px to `.top-area` so the div will clear your header, too.

```
.top-area {
    background: url(../img/matt.png) no-repeat center 78px fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 677px;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-top: 28px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because you used navbar position fixed. if you want to use this add

```
body{padding-top:78px;}

 or

.top-area{margin-top:28px;}
```